# Typescript infer generic param types with union

Tags: typescript

I have been struggling with the codes below for a few hours. Don't understand why `e4` is `string` not `String`?

```
type PropConstructor4<T = any> = { new(...args: any[]): (T & object) } | { (): T }
type e4 = StringConstructor extends PropConstructor4<infer R> ? R : false // why string not String ???
```

I have tested below and I think I could understand.

```
type a4 = StringConstructor extends { new(...args: any[]): (infer R & object) } ? R : false // String
type b4 = StringConstructor extends { (): ( String) } ? true : false // true
type c4 = StringConstructor extends { (): (infer R) } ? R : false // string
```

Also, I couldn't understand why `e5` is `String` not `string`?

```
type PropConstructor5<T = any> = { new(...args: any[]): (T ) } | { (): T }
type e5 = StringConstructor extends PropConstructor5<infer R> ? R : false //why String not string??
```

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR the compiler uses heuristics to give different priorities to different inference sites, and infers the type from the inference site with the highest priority.

---

*Generally* speaking, when TypeScript infers a specific type for a type parameter (the `R` in all your examples), it considers each *inference site*, which is where the type parameter occurs in the expression it's trying to match.  For example, in

```
type P = StringConstructor extends 
    (() => infer R) | { new(...args: any[]): (infer R & object) } ? R : never
//         ^^^^^^^  <-- inference sites -->   ^^^^^^^
```

there are two inference sites for the `R` type parameter.  The compiler's job is to try to match `StringConstructor` with the full expression by inspecting an inference site, coming up with a *candidate* specific type for that site, and then *checking* the full expression to determine if that candidate works when substituted in every site.

Let's test it out with `P` above, by pretending that we're the compiler and seeing what happens if we change *which* inference site to inspect.

---

If the compiler chooses the first inference site to inspect:

```
type P = StringConstructor extends 
    (() => infer R) | { new(...args: any[]): (infer R & object) } ? R : never
//         ^^^^^^^  <-- inspect this
```

In this case, `string` is the candidate it would come up with, since `String("hello")` produces a `string` output.  It could then check that `string` works for the whole expression.  `StringConstructor` does indeed extend `(() => string) | { new(...args: any[]): (string & object) }` because it extends the first member of the union (since `A extends B | C` is true if `A extends B` or `A extends C`), and so `R` would be inferred as `string` if the compiler considers only the first inference site.

---

What about the second inference site?

```
type P = StringConstructor extends 
    (() => infer R) | { new(...args: any[]): (infer R & object) } ? R : never
//                           inspect this --> ~~~~~~~~
```

In this case, `String` is the candidate it would come up with, since `new String("hello")` produces a `String` output.  It would then check that `String` works for the whole expression.  `StringConstructor` does indeed extend `(() => String) | { new(...args: any[]): (String & object) }` because it extends both sides of the union.  (`string` extends `String`, so `() => string` extends `() => String`), and so `R` would be inferred as `String` if the compiler considers only the second inference site.

---

It is also potentially possible that the compiler could consider *both* inference sites at the same time, and synthesize a union/supertype or intersection/subtype of the candidates depending on variance. In this case the parameters are both in a covariant position, so `string | String` or just `String` (since it is a supertype of `string`) would be my guesses if this happens.

---

So then for the above expression, one could plausibly imagine that `string`, `String`, `string | String` comes out.  What actually happens?

```
type P = StringConstructor extends
    (() => infer R) | { new(...args: any[]): (infer R & object) } ? R : never
// string
```

It's `string`.  That means the compiler is giving *priority* to the first inference site.  Compare to what happens in the following:

```
type O = StringConstructor extends
    (() => infer R) | { new(...args: any[]): (infer R) } ? R : never
// String
```

Now, the compiler is giving priority to the second inference site instead.  Somehow, `(infer R & object)` has a lower priority than just `infer R`.

---

So, how does the compiler assign priorities to different inference sites?  I can't pretend to know the full details of this.

It *used* to be laid out in the TypeScript Specification document, but that is long out-of-date and now archived.  See [this section](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3821ef011ada48c14e07e3124c6502a44a3e3856/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#3117-type-inference) if you're curious.  Nowadays there is no specification because the language is changing faster than can be rigorously documented.

There are a few issues in GitHub that touch on this idea of inference site priority.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) for a feature request to allow a site to have zero priority and be never used for inference.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#39295](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39295) and [microsoft/TypeScript#32389](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32389) for issues that stem from developers having a different intuition from what the compiler actually does.

One common thread is that intersections like `(T & {})` have lower priority than types without intersections `T`.  So you can use `T & {}` to lower the priority of a site if it is getting in the way.  And so you that explains why `infer R & object` is not the chosen site for `P`.

Again, I don't know the full details of this, and it probably isn't very enlightening to learn.  If you go through [the type checker code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/TypeScript/master/src/compiler/checker.ts) you might be able to piece together   whether *construct* signature return types have higher priority than *call* signature return types, but I wouldn't recommend writing any programs that depend on such details unless you want to keep revisiting it... one cannot guarantee that such particular inference rules will persist across releases of the language.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.1.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAClC8UDKwBOBLAdgcwMIHtMBnNAVwGNh9UoIAPYCTAEyIFgAoKbqACl4CUCAHxQsAMwg0ASkIA+UAN5RMEAO68AdNoCGqbEQBcUHZhABtALoDjvCVKjSoAMij4ARgCsIlIQF8oAH5HKGNVADcpTgB6aKgSDBxOTlBIKAB5BGQ0LDxCBIoqGnpGFnYuHn4heFF7GXklFXUtXX0jEzMrGz46x38gkLCISNQYuJRE7GSOIA)

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the answer and the issue link. It gives me a lot of inspiration.